# Android Button not listening accepting clicklistener under mapfragment class

Tags: android, google-maps, button

I have a button in this view which also has map class but somehow I cant set a listener to this button:

```
fileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I am not sure this is because this is a map class/fragment or any other reason.

The full class here:

```
/**
 * This shows how to listen to some {@link GoogleMap} events.
 */
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback, OnClickListener {

    private TextView mTapTextView;
    private Button fileBtn;
    private static final int REQUEST_PICK_FILE = 1;
    private File selectedFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mTapTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap_text);
        mTapTextView.setText("Loaded");

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    Button fileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadfile);
        fileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {

            case R.id.loadfile:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FilePicker.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            switch(requestCode) {

                case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:

                    if(data.hasExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH)) {

                        selectedFile = new File
                                (data.getStringExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test single attachment");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"amirfarazmand@gmail.com"});
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Mail with an attachment");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH))));
                        intent.setType("application/pdf");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        googleMap = map;
        enableMyLocation();
    }

   /* private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
    private static final LatLng ADELAIDE = new LatLng(-34.92873, 138.59995);
    private static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.95285, 115.85734); */
    public int i=0;
    public Polygon polygon;
    public Polyline polyline;

    List<LatLng> coordinates=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
   public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
       mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + point);
       if (i==0){
           i=1;
           coordinates.add(point);
           googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                   .position(point)
                   .title(String.valueOf(point.latitude))
                   .snippet(String.valueOf(point.latitude))
                   .rotation((float) -15.0)
                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
           );
       } else if (i==1) {
           i=i+1;
           coordinates.add(point);
           polyline = googleMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                   .add(coordinates.get(0), coordinates.get(1)));
       }else if (i>1){
           coordinates.add(point);
           polyline.remove();
           if (i>2){polygon.remove();};
           polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
               .addAll(coordinates)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
             .strokeWidth(10));
           //polygon = googleMap.addPolygon((new PolygonOptions())
              //     .add(coordinates.get(0), coordinates.get(1),coordinates.get(2)));
           i=i+1;
       }/*else{
           List<LatLng> polygonList = polygon.getPoints();

           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), polygonList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


           polygonList.add(point);
           polygon.remove();
           polygon = googleMap.addPolygon((new PolygonOptions()));
           polygon.setPoints(polygonList);
           i=i+1;
       }*/
   }
    public boolean mapView = true;
    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        if(mapView) {
            mTapTextView.setText("long pressed, point=" + point);
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            mapView=!mapView;
        }else{
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mapView=!mapView;
        }
    }
    //Load coorodinates from file




    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (googleMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
     */
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. If you think that the map is the issue, then remove it and test the button

Comment: You can't call `findViewById` outside of onCreate. Also, did you get a logcat? Please add it to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to declare button and click listner in onCreate() method  rather than outside 
of it.Like:

```
oncreate()
{
    b1=(Button)findviewbyId(R.id.abc);
    b1.setOnclicklistener(this);
}
```

when You implement View.Onclicklistener...You will get override method onClick 
        ....Inside  that based on id you implement your logic.

Answer (score 1):

You should add *listener* inside `onCreate`. Then `override` method for `onClick`.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mTapTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap_text);
        mTapTextView.setText("Loaded");

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Button fileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadfile);
        fileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

`Override` method.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {

            case R.id.loadfile:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FilePicker.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why these line

```
Button fileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadfile);
fileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

are outside onCreate() method ?

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is that because ur Class implements `OnClickListener` instead of `View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

```
Button fileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadfile); 
fileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Your code is dizzy, what I understood is you need to put this code inside onCreate.